# Strongly connected graph: equivalent formulation

Tags: graph-theory

A **digraph**(=directed graph = graph with directed/oriented edges) $X$ is said to be **strongly connected** if for any distinct vertices $v,w$, there is a *directed* path from $v$ to $w$.

In particular in such digraphs, every vertex has an incoming edge and an outgoing edge. My question is, whether the last property characterizes strongly connected digraphs? To be precise,

> Q. Let $X$ be a connected, finite, digraph. Assume that every vertex has at least one incoming and one outgoing edge. Is $X$ strongly connected?

Comment: I presume we make the usual assumptions about simple graphs? No multi-edges and no self-loops? Also, when you say "characterize", it means *if and only if*, correct?

Comment: yes; let us exclude graphs without loops. But, there can be single edge from $v$ to $w$ and also from  $w$ to $v$; since they have different orientations, these are not actually multiple edges. (In *characterize*, it is certainly if and only if, and one direction I mentioned follows from definition of strongly  connected graph; other direction is in question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, for example take a digraph on six vertices $u,v,w,x,y,z$. If the edges are $(u,v),(v,w),(w,u),(x,y),(y,z),(z,x),(u,x),(v,y),(w,z)$ then this is connected and every vertex has at least one incoming and at least one outgoing edge. But there is no directed path from any of $x,y,z$ to any of $u,v,w$.

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to see that having *indegree, outdegree* $\ge 1$ for every vertex is a *necessary* condition for a graph to be strongly connected. Otherwise, you would have an unreachable vertex or a vertex from which there are no paths.

But it is **not** a *sufficient* condition; counterexample below.

Draw two directed triangle graphs and join them by a single directed edge.
[image]

Since the degrees are not balanced, there is a directed path from one strongly connected component to the other, but not the other way around; despite the underlying undirected graph being connected.

Comment: On the other hand, a **sufficient** condition for a (finite) connected digraph to be stronly connected is that every vertex have the same number of incoming as outgoing edges. And, of course, a **necessary and sufficient** condition is that every **set** of vertices, except the empty set and the set of all vertices, have at least one outgoing edge.